# How to run a CTS test or How to run AndroidTestCase

Tags: android, cts

I just learnt some stuff about Android MediaCodec. And I found some demos. Anyway, the demos are not written in a familiar way. The link of the demo is [here](http://bigflake.com/mediacodec/).

Take the 'EncodeAndMuxTest.java' sample for example. It seems like it has something to do with the CTS. But it is an AndroidTestCase . I really don't know how to run this one. Could anyone give me an hint?

Comment: have you found any answer to this?